# Backpack admin panel and user panel

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-backpack

I use a backpack. I have problem with auth admin panel and user panel because Backpack uses authentication.

What do you want to do?
Restricted login.
I have two login panels. One for the user to display information, the other for the administrator.

I want to so that the user can only login to the user panel, and the admin could log in to the user panel and admin panel.

Currently, when the user logs on to the user dashboard to redirect, go to the admin. It does not work that way.

For the user, I have roles and the "User"
For admin I have roles and permissions "Admin"

In backpack i have:

```
'setup_auth_routes' => false,
'setup_dashboard_routes' => false,
```

My routing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix')], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@redirect');
});

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix'),
        'namespace'     => '\Admin',
    ],
    function () {
                // setup the auth routes
        Route::auth();
        Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

                // setup the dashboard routes
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@redirect');
    });
```

What can I do to get it is good working?

Comment: Sounds backwards.. Why didnt you just make 1 login panel and then setup a middleware to check the `accesslevel` of the user to determine whether its a user or admin and then run the redirect via the mware?

Comment: Try to hake Admin middleware and use guard to protect them